# IE8 Style Sheet Issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I am helping to work on a website for my church and I've run into an issue with a style sheet and IE (amazing, right?)

There's a floating search box that if you view in almost every browser, appears correctly. To see that it is correct, the word Search appears in the image in the exact location of the search box. However, if IE8 is in compatibility view, the input box is placed all the way at top right so you can barely make out that there's text above the breadcrumb in the top right.

I've tried forcing IE to use Non-compatibility mode by putting this tag into all my documents, but it doesn't work and doesn't turn off the compatibility mode.

The URL is http://66.165.142.160

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
This is what it looks like in every browser I've tried except IE 8 compatibility mode
[image: Here is what it is supposed to look like]

And this is what IE8 compatibility mode looks like

[image: Here is what it looks like in IE compatibility mode:]

Comment: do you have a screenshot of what this looks like in ie8/compat?  I don't have windoze.

Comment: Yes, main description updated. Thanks.

Comment: Just so you know, IE8 Compatibility Mode = IE7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might help the layout if you use the natural flow of elements i.e., `<div id="social-icons">` placed after `<div id="search">`.

Both of these elements will render better cross browser if they have `float:right; clear:right;` declared on them and then add `<div class="clear">` after the social icons container.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this between your  tags should prevent IE8 from offering compatibility mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Does that work for you?

If not, maybe you can add fix a fix for it inside conditional comment (this will be hidden for all other browsers and applicable to IE7 / compatibility mode only):

```
<!--[if IE 7]>

Here put the IE7 specific css, which will also apply to IE8 compatibility mode.

<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I did ie=edge which is supposed to use the most up to date renderer for whatever version of IE they are using. For some reason, it is still rendering in compatibility mode for people and I don't know why.